# Simplest way to read INPUT outside a FORM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a simple form as

```
<form method="post" action="target.php">
<input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I want to read checkboxes from atable. Thus, checkbox input is outside the `<form>` as

```
<input type="checkbox" name="tick[]" value="'.$value.'" />
```

What is the simplest jQuery action to read the values checked and send them via `POST` by the form?

P.S. Since I have form for each row in the table, I cannot put the entire table within `<form>` tag.

Comment: What are you going to do for your users with JavaScript disabled?

Comment: First I thought of a javascript-free method to do so, but I did not find a practical way. Can you suggest a pure html method for this purpose? That would be ideal!

Comment: What do you mean by javascript-free method of reading the values?????

Comment: You have a single form around the entire table and use the successful submit button to determine which row is in play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - I didn't test it though.

```
$("input[name^=tick]:checked").each(function() {
    $(this).val()  // this line should contain the value of each checked checkbox, you can use it as you want
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the entire for in a single object / array by using jQuery [serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) or [serializeArray()](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) method :

```
alert($('#<idOfForm>').serialize()); // will alert all form values in key / value string
```

or to submit the form using [$.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) :

```
$.post("target.php", $("#<idOfForm>").serialize());
```